# Scrapping KickStarter Through XHR requests

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I would like to scrape KickStarter via XHR requests. However, I get 403 as a response status code despite trying to replicate the exact request. Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced"

params = {
    "google_chrome_workaround": "",
    "woe_id": "0",
    "sort": "magic",
    "seed": "2811118",
    "page": "1"
}

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8",
    "Cookie": "copy-paste-from-the-browser",
    "Referer": "https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": '"Windows"',
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Csrf-Token": "copy-paste-from-the-browser",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
```

Can you please give me any advice on how to scrape this data?